# I need hep with modifying anchor tag parameters based on the checkbox selection

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to add the value of selected checkbox to anchor tag parameter "product-code" and "product-quantity". For example if someone click the first checkbox the product code parameter will be something like product-code="90;1" and product-quantity="1;1". And if someone also check the second checkbox the product code parameter will be like product-code="90;1;2" and product-quantity="1;1;1". Same for the third parameter. Can someone help me with this how I can get this done with the help of jquery?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Apple" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="Banana" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="Orange" value="3">

<a href="#buy" class="avangate_button btn btn-primary" product-code="90" product-quantity="1">Order Now!</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work for you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(){
                let newProductCode = defaultProductCode = $('.avangate_button').attr('product-code').split(';')[0];
                let newProductQty = defaultProductQty = $('.avangate_button').attr('product-quantity').split(';')[0];   

                $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function( index ) {
                    if($(this).is(':checked')){
                        newProductQty = newProductQty + ";" + 1;
                        newProductCode = newProductCode + ";" + $(this).val();
                    }
                });
                $('.avangate_button').attr('product-code',newProductCode);
                $('.avangate_button').attr('product-quantity',newProductQty);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Apple" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Banana" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Orange" value="3">
    <a href="#buy" class="avangate_button btn btn-primary" product-code="90" product-quantity="1">Order Now!</a>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution. It worked like a charm in case if input is as checkbox. How to do this if input is as radio buttons and if radio button with empty value is checked product code has nothing except original value and product quantity has only 1 in the input.

Answer (score 0):

its simple you just create two variables e.g productCode & productQuantity and place it anchor tag . Create a function to set upper variables value and execute this function on "onChange" event of checkbox .

**here is the code :**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Apple" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="Banana" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="Orange" value="3">

<a href="#buy" class="avangate_button btn btn-primary" product-code="90" 
product- 
quantity="1">Order Now!</a>

var productCode = "90";
var productQuantity = "1";

$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(val){
productCode = productCode + ";" + val;
productQuantity = productQuantity + ";" + val;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. You are storing the value in variables. I need updated values in anchor tag attributes.

Comment: in anchor tag you should place variable which I have created


<a href="#buy" class="avangate_button btn btn-primary" product-code=productCode 
product- 
quantity=productQuantity>Order Now!</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you really *want* to work with the attribute `product-code` then the following snippet should do the trick:

```js
const a=document.querySelector("a");
const cbs=[...document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")];
cbs.forEach(cb=>cb.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  a.setAttribute("product-code",[90,...cbs.filter(c=>c.checked).map(c=>c.value)].join(";"));
  console.log(a);
}));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="Apple" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="Banana" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="Orange" value="3">

<a href="#buy" class="avangate_button btn btn-primary" product-code="90" 
product- 
quantity="1">Order Now!</a>
```

**Please note:**

According to the [MDM web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) the `<a>` element does not actually support an attribute `product-code`. You should therefore rather use something like `data-product-code` instead.